# python import results in nameerror

Tags: python, import, nameerror

This seems pretty basic, so I must be missing something obvious. Goal is to import a module from the same directory. I've broken it down about as simple as I can and I'm getting the `nameerror`.

file `import_this.py`:

```
def my_function(number) :
    print number + 2
```

file `import_test.py`:

```
import import_this
my_function(2)
```

Do I have to specify the directory the import file is in? (It's in the same as the test file). Also, can I test to see what modules are imported?

Comment: You have to use the module name to access the function like, import_this.my_function(2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the function incorrectly.

Either use the following

```
import import_this
import_this.my_function(2)
```

or do,

```
from import_this import my_function
my_function(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (apart from @mu's answer above),

```
>>>import import_this as it
```

.. and then,

```
>>> it.my_function(2)
```