# Use Python functions across different files and return multiple values to the caller(s)

Tags: python, list, function, variables, return

I am wondering how to return a list or string into a variable. For example I have the following code split in two files here:

File1.py

```
def example():
    number = 3
    return number
```

file2.py

```
import file1
name = example()
```

This function gives me an error saying that example() is not defined.

Also is there any way to get two variables out of a function as well?

For example:

```
def example():
    number = 3
    list = [1 , 2]
    return list
    return number
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python import results in nameerror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783954/python-import-results-in-nameerror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the function.

```py
from file1 import example
name = example()
```

or

```py
import file1
name = file1.example()
```

To return n values from a function you would return some sequence, the most common case for that purpose is using a `tuple`. You can just comma separate the values in the return statement.

```py
def example():
    number = 3
    lst = [1 , 2]
    return lst, number

lst, number = example()

values = example()
lst = values[0]
number = values[1]

lst, number = values[0], values[1]
```

Comment: @AustinReedVlog, you only imported the module file1. Take another look at this answer, it tells you what you need to do

Comment: You are importing the module and expecting it to be automatically unpacked for you. Read the answer again.

Answer (score 0):

In `file2.py` it should be used:

```
import file1
name = file1.example()
```

or also you can only import `example()` function:

```
from file1 import example
name = example()
```

Now when you type `name` variable, you get your desired value.

> Also is there any way to get two variables out of a function as well?

In my opinion, it would be better if you ask two separate questions; anyhow, here you are:

```
def example():
    my_number = 3
    my_list = [1, 2]
    return my_list, my_number


list1, number1 = example()
example1 = example()

list1 = example1[0]
number1 = example1[1]
print(number1, list1)
```

I have modified your code in Python readable format and edited your variable names.